# Trying to figure out how to close old content when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, css

I have a very basic tab setup on my website and I managed to show the content I need when I press a tab. However, that content stays visible when I click another tab.
I also tried to write a function to remove all the clicked-on tab content before showing me the next one but the problem is it gives me an addEventListener error and it's been driving me crazy for the last couple of days.

```js
const tabs = function(panelClass, numClass, techNum) {
  document.getElementById(panelClass).addEventListener("click", () => {



    removeStuff();

    document.querySelector('.slide').style.display = "flex"
    document.querySelector(numClass).style.display = "flex"
    document.querySelector(techNum).style.display = "block"

  });


};

function removeStuff(parameter) {
  document.querySelector(parameter).addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector('.slide').style.display = "none"
    document.querySelector('.content-slide').style.display = "none"
    document.querySelector('.picture').style.display = "none"


  });

}

removeStuff('tab1');
removeStuff('tab2');
tabs('tab1', '.two', ".p2");
tabs('tab2', '.one', ".p1");
```

```html
<img class='picture p2' src="./picture.jpg" height=140px;alt="">
<img class='picture p1 ' src="./picture.jpg" height=140px;alt="">

<div class="slide">

  <!-- Slide 1 -->


  <div class="content-slide active one">

    <h3>Some text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
   

<!-- Slide2 -->

<div class="content-slide two">



  <h3>Some Text</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and better approach would be to check that `document.getElementById(someID)`  is not null before adding an event listener to it:

Demo code:

```js
const tabs = function(panelClass, numClass, techNum) {

   var panel =  document.getElementById(panelClass);
   if(panel){
      panel.addEventListener("click", () => {
      removeStuff();

      document.querySelector('.slide').style.display = "flex"
      document.querySelector(numClass).style.display = "flex"
      document.querySelector(techNum).style.display = "block"

    });
  }
};

function removeStuff(parameter) {
 var tab = document.querySelector(parameter);
 if(tab){
      tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
      document.querySelector('.slide').style.display = "none"
      document.querySelector('.content-slide').style.display = "none"
      document.querySelector('.picture').style.display = "none"
    });
  }
}

removeStuff('tab1');
removeStuff('tab2');
tabs('tab1', '.two', ".p2");
tabs('tab2', '.one', ".p1");
```

```html
<img class='picture p2' src="./picture.jpg" height=140px;alt="">
<img class='picture p1 ' src="./picture.jpg" height=140px;alt="">

<div class="slide">

  <!-- Slide 1 -->
  <div  class="content-slide active one">

    <h3>Some text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Slide2 -->

<div class="content-slide two">



  <h3>Some Text</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this an actual copy-and-paste of your code, a couple of things stand out:

1. You closed your main slide div before "content-slide two". Given the final <div> tag in your markup...that doesn't look like what you meant to do. One way or another, you have an extra div tag.
2. Your call to removeStuff() in the tabs function does not pass a parameter. That's going to cause some issues with querySelector; you'd be invoking addEventListener on an undefined object in the removeStuff() function.

It's likely that these two things are part of the problems you're experiencing.

Comment: You were right about the </div>. I corrected the snipped.